# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

Каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь открыть абсолютно любой текстовый файл, мне выдается эта ошибка. Может ли мой Python во всех текстовых файлах видеть байты? И как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку при открытии файла. Ну там `encoding='utf-8'` или `'cp1251'` или `'cp866'`, я ж не знаю, в какой кодировке у вас файлы.